# Microsoft Edge Chromium: How to use "Install this site as an app" (PWA) via PowerShell / Command Prompt

Tags: powershell, command-prompt, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-chromium

is there any opportunity to use the very interesting "Install this site as an app" feature of the new Microsoft Edge Chromium Web Browser via PowerShell or Command Prompt? This would be very satisfying since one could run a script-based customization so that specific intranet applications would be as easy accessible for users in Windows as usual apps.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any piece of information on that topic in Microsoft's Knowledge Base sites. Is there no dedicated (PowerShell) command or do I struggle to see the wood for the trees? :/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also didn't find any information about using this feature via PowerShell or Command Prompt. I think it's impossible to do this. If you want to use the PWA more conveniently, you can create shortcut of PWA on desktop by right clicking the installed PWA in Edge-> select Create shortcut: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVgVu.png.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, it's not what I was looking for, but at least it is interesting that the internal site "edge://apps" exists! Hopefully, MS is going to add an opportunity to control edge chromium via power shell in a more satisfactory way.

Comment: I have been wanting this feature ever since Microsoft added the ability to "Install this site as an App".  When I was doing beta testing for New Edge, I suggested it a few times via Feedback, and all I heard was crickets.

Answer (score 0):

[Chromium](https://chromium.org) would need to implement it, because Edge is based on [Chromium](https://chromium.org).